# How to get a list of base names of InfluxDB series?

Tags: time-series, influxdb

InfluxDB's `SHOW SERIES` query returns a list of all series-tag-value combinations existing in the database.

How can I get a list of just the series' "base names" (without tags)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Series without tags is just a measurement.

```
SHOW MEASUREMENTS [ON <database_name>]
```